# Where can I ask technical non-conforming questions?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I ask questions that aren't Stack Overflow questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-stack-overflow-questions)

I understand that SE place is not good for certain questions that do not conform with some democratically elected style, what alternatives exist for these questions?

Comment: For background on this question please refer to the question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110493/where-should-i-ask-difficult-technical-questions)

Comment: The linked question is more about the subject matter. The question here is more about policy, it seems.

Answer (score 3):

There is quite a few mentioned in the linked possible duplicate [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-stack-overflow-questions).

However based on the requirements that you specify I would suggest looking at sites like:

[Quora](http://www.quora.com/)

> A continually improving collection of questions and answers created, edited, and organized by everyone who uses it.

You can sign up [here](http://www.quora.com/signup/index).
<sub>I did not complete the process</sub>

[Yahoo Answer](http://answers.yahoo.com/)

*No, I am not being sarcastic*. There is some good answers among all the fluff and they do allow a much broader range of questions.

Comment: thank you, unfortunately quora requires an invitation.

Comment: @StefanoBorini I updated my answer.